# создать вектор пар. вещественные значения точек должны быть случайными

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

помогите пожалуйста с заданием. создать вектор пар на 10 точек vector pair вещественные значения точек должны быть случайными из диапазона (-100,100).

Comment: Давайте начнем. Как создать вектор пар, думаю, напишете? Как напишете, пойдем дальше. Намек к уроку первому - вектор для элементов типа `type` объявляется как `vector<type>`, а пары можно написать свои - соответствующую структуру, или взять стандартный класс `pair` - как именно - посмотрите в своих конспектах. Как сделаете это - пишите, продолжим работу...

Comment: мне здесь конкретно надо как заполнить вектор типа pair по условию

Comment: Ну что ж, вам уже написали. Научить вас не удалось, вы вынесли другой урок - что учиться не надо, найдется кто-то, кто сделает за вас...

Comment: {V[i].first = (a + rand() % b+100) + (a + rand() % b+100) / 100.0}

a - минимальное значение, в - максимальное | 

+100 в вашем случае потому что если вы к -100 добавите 100, то получается диапазон (-100;0) | 

Первая часть (a + rand() % b+100) - целая часть | 

Вторая часть + (a + rand() % b+100) / 100.0 - прибавляется дробная. |

Comment: @Павел, спасибо большое, не смог сам додуматься до заполнения(

Comment: @Руслан рандомы и для меня темный лес, надо учиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите генератор псевдослучайных чисел - std::mt19937_64

и дистрибьюшен - std::uniform_int_distributio

Заведите вектор пар и генерируйте туда данные через метод вектора push_back

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

int GenRandomUInt(int lowB, int upperB) {
  static std::random_device r_dev{};
  static std::mt19937_64 mt_engine(r_dev());
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<> u_int_d(lowB, upperB);

  return static_cast<uint64_t>(u_int_d(mt_engine));
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> dots;

  for (int i{0x0}; i < 0xA; ++i) {
      dots.push_back({GenRandomUInt(-100, 100), GenRandomUInt(-100, 100)});
  }

  for (const auto& pair : dots) {
      std::cout << "x : " << pair.first << " y : " << pair.second << std::endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```